# Fragment Transaction - Erro commit already called

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho esse método que verifica qul o fragment inflar em minha view:

```
private void startFragment(int code) {
    switch (code) {
        case 1:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, MesAnterior.newInstance(0));
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, MesAtual.newInstance(1));
            break;
        case 3:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, MesProximo.newInstance(2));
            break;
    }

    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Eu tenho um fragment (xml) que recebera o fragment.

no primeiro clique no botao ele vai sem problemas, mas no segundo ele da o erro `commit already called`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve estar a fazer o *commit* de uma *transaction* sem fazer `beginTransaction()`.
Uma possível solução é fazê-la no inicio do método `startFragment()`.

Por outro lado deve garantir que `code` apenas terá os valores 1, 2 ou 3.
Declare, para isso, um *enum* que represente cada um desses códigos:

```
public enum FragmentCode {
   MES_ANTERIOR,
   MES_ATUAL,
   MES_PROXIMO
}
```

Altere o método `startFragment()` assim:

```
private void startFragment(FragmentCode code) {

    fragmentTransaction.beginTransaction();

    switch (code) {
        case MES_ANTERIOR:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, MesAnterior.newInstance(0));
            break;
        case MES_ATUAL:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, MesAtual.newInstance(1));
            break;
        case MES_PROXIMO:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, MesProximo.newInstance(2));
            break;
    }

    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```